# Change Global database timeout duration in Oracle SQL with query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, timeout

I want to change my global timeout duration for all database like **global timeout**.
How can I do that **with query** in OracleSQL.

- Example for MySQL:

```
SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000;
SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT
```

Comment: OracleDB and MySQL are not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you wanted:

> By default, the ddl_lock_timeout parameter is set to zero seconds to
> wait, making it equivalent to the earlier NOWAIT behavior.  But this
> can easily be changed to make DDL run in WAIT mode by setting
> ddl_lock_timeout to a non-zero value:

```
alter session set ddl_lock_timeout= 60
```

> Now, DDL will wait 60 seconds before aborting with a ORA-00054 error.

Comment: well, I got it but I have another problem, I set the global wait_time = 10 in mysql but I dont know how to test it if I submit it.

Comment: Hi @Ash, that is another problem for another question. Also please note that this is  the solution for Oracle not for MySQL, you asked something for Oracle and I provided. If this answer is correct please accept it as correct and open a new question with your new problem...

Comment: okey I ll do it accept ur answer for oracle, thx for all, I ll open another question.